# How do I get these pictures in a straight line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a gallery page using bootstrap , But the images in my code are supposed to be in two straight rows, but instead the lower row breaks into two, with the first three pictures much lower than the last.

What is causing this and how do I fix this without making it slip under the navbar?

**=> HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="Author" content="James Vivian">
<meta name="Original Filename" content="index">
<meta name="Date Created" content="8/6/2017">
<meta name="Version" content="Version 1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="custom%20styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!—Define the Responsive Button-->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">    
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> <!—Define the Site Title--> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>  
        </div>
    <!—Define the Menu-->
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>

            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>
<div class="well">

<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 picture">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo1.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo2.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo3.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo4.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo5.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo6.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo7.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo8.jpg">   
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center">
&copy; Starlight Sports<br>All Rights Reserved</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3 /jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**=> CSS :**

```
.
 navbar-nav {float: right; margin:0; } 

#carousel {margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:0px;
} 
footer {margin-top:20px; 
color:white;}
```

I have to use my CSS on multiple pages, hence the carousel.

Comment: please provide working snippet code.

Comment: upload snippet/fiddle please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work. if not, then please provide the screenshot.

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 picture">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo1.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo2.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo3.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo4.jpg">   
    </span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo5.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo6.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo7.jpg">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/photo8.jpg">   
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need two divs with class row. In bootstrap , a row consists of 12 column blocks. If you say class is `.col-lg-3` that means the column has 25% of the row width. So in your case, to have 2 rows with 8 images, you need to break rows and columns like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap your `row` classes in `container` classes. You might want to replace `col-sm-12` with `col-xs-12` since `sm` sizes are for tablets and might still be too wide for you, or might as well remove it.

```css
.navbar-nav {float: right; margin:0; } 

#carousel {margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:0px;
} 
footer {margin-top:20px; 
color:white;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!—Define the Responsive Button-->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">    
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> <!—Define the Site Title--> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>  
        </div>
    <!—Define the Menu-->
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>

            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>
<div class="well">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-3 picture">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>

    <span class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">   
    </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center">
&copy; Starlight Sports<br>All Rights Reserved</footer>
```

For you to have them display as 2 straight rows, wrap 4 of each in a `row` class within a single `container`